# What is best optimizer for Classify images of clothing

Tags: python, keras

I try to use Keras library in python. Definitely this example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification.
What is best loss,hyper parameters and optimizer for this example?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Asking for recommendations or references is *specifically* listed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up any standard example such as MNIST classification for reference.
Usually for classification cross entropy loss is used. The optimizer is subjective and depends on the problem. SGD and Adam are common.
For LR you can start with 10^(-3) and keep reducing if the validation loss doesn't decrease after a certain number of iterations.